# How to disable Ignite's GridUpdateNotifier

Tags: ignite

How to disable GridUpdateNotifier?

After I start my application with embedded Ignite (using Spring), eventually i will get this message in the log:
`ignite-update-notifier-timer Your version is up to date`

I've tried to set environment variable `ignite.update.notifier.enabled.by.default` to `false`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently name of this environment variable have changed.
Now it's `IGNITE_UPDATE_NOTIFIER` defined in [IgniteSystemProperties](https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/390c6a8cc94b9cdbaeaf3623e81f2c85a5222d45/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSystemProperties.java)